# Auto posts being posted by someone in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a website in which only blog section is created in Wordpress, while other sections of the site are normal HTML pages.

For last few weeks, a bot or a person is successful in posting posts to my Wordpress blog automatically, without having access to admin area. Sometime the posts are posted in previous dates, sometime on current dates and sometime scheduled for a future date.

Also it seems that they try to auto post comments against the blog post they add automatically, but I have disabled comments in Wordpress settings. To overcome this, they continue to submit a contact form outside the Wordpress installation folder. I added the code to let me know from which page the form is being submitted, each time its written http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register

For the security measures, things done are:

I have
- checked .htaccess file
- changed the default admin url /wp-admin/ to an other
- installed security plugin https://ithemes.com/security/
- checked admin area of wordpress, no user is present other than administrator
- updated the admin area password with extremely strong one

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Add a log at your server, and check the remote address

Comment: Log is already being created on the server but the problem is the server is nginx based and the log always show the IP address of the server not actual remote IP address in the log. This is how nginx based server works as per the server guys

Comment: You can a put a log by yourself

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before. In my case it was a vulnerable plugin. It's likely there's a script somewhere on your server that's letting the requests through. If it's a process, you'll need to kill it as well as remove the originating script.

The first thing you may want to do is ensure every file and folder in wp-content really belongs there and isn't compromised. Check the timestamps and delete any suspicious plugins/themes that you're not using. If you don't have the time or skills to recognize suspicious code, consider Securi. It's not free but they definitely will figure it out for you.

This command will show you the last modified .php files:

```
find / -iname "*.php" -mtime -1 -print
```

This command will let you see the origin of all your traffic.

```
tcpdump -A -i eth0 -s 1500 port not 22
```

More info here:
https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-identify-the-bad-processes-on-a-hacked-linux-box/

Comment: On the website, only Yoast plugin was installed other than the default Wordpress plugins. Even no new theme was installed, we used one of the default theme's from the Wordpress. Checked the modified files and any extra files, couldn't find any. So for now, I have re-installed fresh copy of Wordpress and transferred data to it. Approx 24 hours passed, no new post or comment till now. Le'ts see how it goes!

Comment: Interesting. It could be that xmlrpc is the culprit. If you're not using it, it may benefit you to add this to your functions.php `add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');`